# Search on Assets (pixel & tonic) Meta Data

Tags: assets

Hi I need help with searching assets image data via the front end of my site. I have a single entry for a page with an assets field powered gallery on it.

The multiple images for the gallery are added via an assets field and pulled into my template with an assets tag pair e.g.

{page-gallery}
content
{/page-gallery}

Is it possible to do a search on assets meta for the content within the tag pair ?

My goal is to create a simple image library that can searched on assets meta content.

e.g. {page-gallery:title}

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Assets has field tag parameters that correspond with each of its metadata fields (see http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/field.html).

If you pass your ‘title’ search input as POST data on the page, you can fetch that value and pass it into Assets’ `title` param using the [GET/POST Parameters](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/get-post-parameters) add-on like so:

```
{page-gallery title="{exp:parameters post='asset_title'}"}
    ...
{/page-gallery}
```

Comment: [http://www.porvair-sciences.com/search/image-search] .. seems to generate the right output but something strange is happening.

Comment: I used '{exp:channel:entries}
{page-gallery title="{exp:parameters:post name="title"}"}
{title}
{/page-gallery}
 {/exp:channel:entries}'

Comment: But the image seems to jump out of place and fail. If however I hardcode the {page-gallery title="204003"} it works as expected.

Comment: Any help is massively appreciated ta.